# How not-using named queries improves cube performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, ssas

With reference to this site, [SSAS Interview Questions and Answers](http://www.msbiguide.com/2012/11/ssas-interview-questions-and-answers/),

We should avoid named queries to tune the performance. I have not got any answers/links about how it affects the performance of it.

My question is, how it affects cube performance if we don't use named queries in data source view instead of using it?

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see that too. Smells like a wrong question to me. Unless it is "flatten the values into a separate column / cube instead of querying dynamically" I reall fail to see more than a trivial performance overhead (on a non relevant scale) for the query lookup.